# Laravel: Form Validation not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to use the Form Validation to validate the data coming from the clients I cannot properly validate it because the `authorize()` method is being executed even if the validation rules contained in `rules()` are violated.

This is the code:

```
class PostAssignRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        $params = $this->request->all();

        if(User::find($params['userId'])->company != Auth::user()->company)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'userId' => 'required|exists:users,id',
            'taskId' => 'required|exists:tasks,id'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

In this example the `User::find()` is executed even if the `userId` param is not set.

I also noticed that if the `authorize()` method just returns `true` then I receive a `422` response telling me that the `userId` parameter is missing.

How am I supposed to deal with this? I would like first to check the rules and then if those are OK proceed with the authorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authorization and validation is called in `ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait@validate`:

```
public function validate()
{
    $instance = $this->getValidatorInstance();

    if ( ! $this->passesAuthorization())
    {
        $this->failedAuthorization();
    }
    elseif ( ! $instance->passes())
    {
        $this->failedValidation($instance);
    }
}
```

You can change the order by overriding the `validate` method in your form request. If you want this for all your requests do it in the base class `App\Http\Requests\Request`:

```
public function validate()
{
    $instance = $this->getValidatorInstance();

    if ( ! $instance->passes())
    {
        $this->failedValidation($instance);
    }
    elseif ( ! $this->passesAuthorization())
    {
        $this->failedAuthorization();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this kind of approach, looks like it's the cleanest way. I found the `ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait` but I didn't notice that it was used by `FormRequest` so I didn't think of overriding it. Nice find :-)

Comment: You're welcome. And I'm pretty sure it is the cleanest way... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Laravel executes authorize() first then you need to do manual check in there. I guess it was not meant for using it the way you are doing.

If you get 422 response then you are doing Ajax request. You can use response 422 to process form validation errors in you client side code.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that maybe it would make more sense to check the data first and then, if it's valid, perform any logic with the right data. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rather use an Middleware for your check. A Middleware fits more your purpose. The following code should be moved to a Middleware.

```
if(User::find($params['userId'])->company != Auth::user()->company)
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Middleware is not for form validation

Comment: I didn't mean the form validation, I was referring to `if(User::find($params['userId'])->company != Auth::user()->company)
        {
            return false;
        }`

Comment: I use middleware for more generic purposes. In this case I opted for form validation since the validation rules can be very specific based on each API route (plus I can inject them in the controllers easily).

Comment: I am not quit sure, but I think it is also possible to access the FormRequest data from the Request object within the handle() method in an Middleware there for example you can access the rules. Laravel 5.1 will present Middleware Parameters, which will make it easier to write nicer code :)